# How to work multiple pull requests to a single GitHub project?

Tags: github

Let's say that for a single GH repo I have changes to file A, and unrelated changes to file B.

Since the changes are unrelated, they don't belong in the same PR.

Suppose I do this:

- Push change A to branch a.
- Push change B to branch b.
- Wait for comments/approvals for both.

When one, say A, is approved and merged, won't that foul the merge for B (which does not have change A)?

If so, is there a workflow where I can have PRs for multiple branches that will work?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: If the change made in branch A do not conflict with the changes in branch B, there is no problem. Either push will work. Perhaps you can modify your question to show a problem that needs to be solved. The details might clarify what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you have changes in separate files, then those changes aren't going to have conflicts.  It's possible to have multiple pull requests open for non-conflicting changes at once and have all of them be merged successfully.  This is true whether those multiple merges come from one person or from multiple.

In fact, this is part of why many version control systems (like Git) exist: they allow multiple people to collaborate on mutually independent changes at the same time and include them via merges as they become ready.

So you should end up with no problems with these multiple PRs if they really touch only independent files, or even if they touch the same files but have no conflicts.

Comment: Ok.  I have the first PR open with the first file.  When I offer to open the second PR, the file comparison shows diffs for both files (which I've seen before, and which causes my fears).  Is that expected?  If I go ahead and open the second PR, all will be well regardless of which is merged first?

Comment: You need to create your second pull request off the main branch, not off the branch that you created your first pull request from.  If your main branch is `main` and your pull request branches are `A` and `B`, switch to `B` and run `git rebase --onto main A`, which will rebase it onto the main branch instead of A.